# LDAP Error in IIS7.5 while using windows Authentication

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, ldap, iis-7.5, windows-authentication

I'm having facing  problemind with  LDAP, its bit strange one. My Web server is IIS7.5(windows server 2008 R2). Its configured to use windows Authentication. I've pasted my asp page below.

Web browser is  IE8, Have added the website to intranet zone and enabled  send, user details if intranet zone in security tab->custom level. Intigrated windows authentication is enabled in advanced tab.

Everything works fine for 20minutes(Session time setiing  and other default time out settings are for 20min). After 20minutes I get it ASP runtime error. Which says method or property memberOf for object objUser is not supported. When I get below error I change the Authentication type to basic Authentication. It prompts for windows credentials and works fine. After that I again revert back to windows authentication. And it works for sometime.

Not sure if IIS7.5 id configured with basic authentication enabled and IE8 configured as above, still why it prompts for windows Credential. Though windows Authentication mode doesn't prompt for credential, It works fine but for certain period. Can any one explain me why this strange behaviour and solution to fix this one?

```
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" %>
<%
 Option Explicit

Dim oADSysInfo
Dim objUser
Dim strGroupData
Dim strUserDN
 Dim arrGroups
 Dim strGroup
 Dim wsObject
 Dim netSys
 Dim strUsrDomain

 strGroupData = ""
    Set wsObject = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 Set netSys =   CreateObject("WScript.Network")

 strUsrDomain = netSys.UserDomain
Set oADSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")

 If err.number <> 0 Then
 'getLDAPGroupInfo = strGroupData
  'wsObject.popup("Error"& e.decription)
 'Exit Function
 End If
 strUserDN = oADSysInfo.UserName
 Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://"& strUserDN)
 arrGroups = objUser.memberOf

  If IsEmpty(arrGroups) Then
  'Wscript.Echo "Member of no groups"
 ElseIf (TypeName(arrGroups) = "String") Then
  'Wscript.Echo "Member of group " & arrGroups
  strGroupData = arrGroups
 Else

  For Each strGroup In arrGroups
   strGroupData = strGroupData & "," & strGroup
 Next
  'strGroupData = arrGroups


 End If 
     Response.Write(strGroupData)
%>
```

Comment: On invetigating further I noticed that issue occurs after 20 minutes since process idle time out was set to 20 min. In event log I found that WAS event, which read worker process was shutdown due to inactivity for specified idle time out. New worker process will be created as and when required. From this I asume that Worker process spawned uses different setting, because of which its failing

Comment: Today I had found out that it also works fine after WAS even t mentioned in previous comments, if I access web site using localhost. But asks for credentials(I assume basic authentication is on). Afterwards I can even use webapplication from other browser with windows authentication on. I'm not sure which is actaully causing the problem,LDAP, IIS or is Some IIS settings overridding my website settings?

Comment: The issue mentioned yesterday were all indticators of"double-hop issue". Is there any simple mechansim to fix this issue at webserver level and not touch LDAP server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I employed rather simple solution.

Solution I employed was as follows.

1. My Application is running under specific user identity(Physical path credential and Application pool idenity set to DNS account)
2. I created another page with above code and ran under applcation pool identity(SPN) and there by created a primary token key between Active Directory server and Webserver server
3. Using that key I again connected to LDAP to query user related info by calling above code under virtual directory having  windows authentication and and running under user identity, there by getting user details.

If you are using asp.net programmatically impersonate user and get user detail from ldap and on application start create primary token by connecting ldap, The primary key persists till worker process is killed